# How to send array of double data type over network using socket?

Tags: c, embedded-linux

I want to send a structure which contains several double data type elements using network socket. Receivers can be of different architecture. What will be better optimized approach to do this except converting it to a string?

Comment: You open a socket, call `connect()` or `bind()` depending on whether it's the client or the server socket, and the use `read()` and `write()`, but be careful with endianness.

Comment: When sending `double` you need to take care of more issues than just endianness. Some info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084279/host-to-network-double

Comment: As @DrKoch recommended, JSON or something similar is worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

On a socket connection exists nothing but raw bytes. So you have to do two things:

1. Convert your double into bytes in a way the receiver can understand. This is rather complicated for doubles see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084279/host-to-network-double)
2. Invent some field separator which you send between the individual doubles.

After all it is a bad idea to reinvent the wheel. You could use some established format like XML or JSON.